# SSAS: programatically search and loop through calculated members in .NET / C#

Tags: c#, ssas

Since for one reason or the other the Visual Studio Plugin BIDS Helper no longer works for us, I started developing a small tool in order to maintain roles, perspectives etc. in a multidimensional cube hosted on a SSAS Server.

Especially concerning the maintenance of perspectives I stumbled about a problem, which is giving me a severe headache:

I am using Microsoft.AnalysisServices, which provides the possibility to get e.g. all Cube Dimensions or all Measure Groups and Measures and compare these against the ones included in a certain perspective. However, this doesn't seem to be the case for calculated members (`CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[...]` within the CubeScript): if I try to find these in the measures (MeasureGroup.Measures, Cube.AllMeasures), no rows are returned - but if I check the perspectives, I can find them in Perspective.PerspectiveCalculations.

However, this results in the problem, that a new calculated member, which is not yet included in any perspective, won't be found by my tool.

Is there any possibility, to find the calculated members without string-splitting the Cube MDX Script?

Comment: You can use the SSAS DMV to get the calculations (called Formula) for your measures. You can run these queries against your SSAS from your C# code. DMV details here: https://bennyaustin.com/2011/03/01/ssas-dmv-queries-cube-metadata/

Comment: @Subbu thank you very much! I'll check this out. Looks quite promising on first glance.